# Prevent users from clicking on the web browser using Window Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to prevent users from clicking on the web browser. I want user to see item on web browser with scroll.
I used

```
AllowNavigation:False;
```

and

```
((Control)webBrowser1).Enabled = false;.
```

AllowNavigation:False; not working in some links and ((control)webBrowser1). Enabled = false is disabling the scrollbars. I also tried

```
Win32.EnableWindow(webBrowser1.Handle, false)
```

but it is blocking the scrollbar as well. Is there any other solution other than these.

Comment: Can you give an example of a webpage you are trying to display in this manner and what links are still working?

Comment: @Idle_Mind I am opening the htmlBody with the DocumentText property. I don't want the user to be able to click on it because the htmlbody may contain spam links. I also blocked the right click option. I'm looking for a solution to prevent a user from performing events on the web browser other than scrolling.